# nested values of form vars from an http request in golang

Tags: http, go

I come from a PHP background and I'm trying to learn Go.

In the past, I can run this command from bash:

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.12.107/restfulendpoint.php \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-d \
"menu[0][name]=pizza&menu[0][price]=12.00&menu[1][name]=orange juice&menu[1][price]=1.00"
```

My `restfulendpoint.php` will naturally receive a `POST` array that is structured in a nested format like so

```
Array
(
    [menu] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => pizza
                    [price] => 12.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => orange juice
                    [price] => 1.00
                )

        )

)
```

I then created a go script that I hope would produce a similar behaviour.  I wrote this `restfulendpoint.go`

```
func Post(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  url := mux.Vars(r)
  r.ParseForm()
  qs := r.Form
  log.Println(qs)
}
```

But when I receive the POST content, I get a structure like this:

```
map[menu[0][price]:[12.00] menu[1][name]:[orange juice] menu[1][price]:[1.00] menu[0][name]:[pizza]]
```

Go is treating each `map[<int>][price|name]` as a separate key in a map.   What I really want is an output like this:

```
map[menu:[map[name:pizza price:12.00] map[name:pizza price:12.00]]]
```

Is there a convention I should follow in my `curl` call to my `restfulendpoint.go` so that I can naturally receive the data in a schema were each menu item has a name and price property? Or is there something I should do in my go script to preserve the data schema?

Comment: There is no such thing as nested values in application/x-www-form-urlencoded; that's why [Request.Form](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) is of type `map[string][]string`. The `menu[0][name]` stuff is an invention by PHP and you have to decode the form yourself if you want equivalent semantics. Or use an encoding that does support complex values, such as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like go's `ParseForm` doesn't cater for the format you use to encode hierarchical structure. I think you're faced with either reading the body as raw, then parsing it yourself, or, if you have the option to change the post format, simply sending the body as JSON instead of a form.

Comment: I ended up passing complex data structures as a JSON string that I later unmarshal